# When do header(..) statements take effect in PHP?

Tags: php, header

1. after all stuff behind is run
2. immediately

Which is the case? Can anyone verify this?

Answer (score 1):

Refer the following link.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 1):

To make sure that a page is directly redirected, add a exit; after the header.

Answer (score 0):

depends on the output_buffering setting
`headers_sent()` function can verify

Answer (score 0):

If output buffering is disabled then it will be sent immediately. It must be sent before any other content (however you can perform processing logic before sending the header)

Comment: Does PHP disable ob by default?

Comment: I believe so in most configurations. Of course this depends on your host. You can force output buffering by calling ob_start() before outputting anything and ob_end_flush() when you've output everything.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on output buffering, but the PHP interpreter still only uses them after having interpreted all the code before, just like a normal function. Still, there must not be any HTML before a `header()`, or things will screw up.